# Visual Studio: Pass Arguments to an Executable in the Compiler Post-Build Events

Tags: c#, visual-studio, post-build-event

I'm trying to run an executable to change my application configuration in the post-build events in visual studio. Depending if the configuration is Debug or Release, I want to pass arguments to my executable in order to execute my configuration changer correctly. Here is what I've done:

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release 
(
"$(ProjectDir)ConfigurationGenerator\ConfigurationGenerator.exe" Release $(OutDir)applicationConfiguration.config 
)

if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug 
(
"$(ProjectDir)ConfigurationGenerator\ConfigurationGenerator.exe" Debug $(OutDir)applicationConfiguration.config
)
```

So, the "Debug" and the "Release" are the argument #1 and the "$(OutDir)applicationConfiguration.config" is the argument #2 in this case. On each time that I try to run my applicatoin, it crashes the build and it returns me in the error lists window that my application stopped with the exit code 3. Any Idea?

Comment: You have described what you've done, but you have not described what the problem is with it.

Comment: Okay, I'll edit it

Comment: Hopefully that utility does more than just set the exit code when it fails.  Look in the Output window for the diagnostic message it spits out.  In general you need to put a file path argument in "double quotes" so that spaces in the path don't cause trouble.  The exit code *sometimes* equals the Windows error, 3 == path not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you even need a conditional?  Just pass in the `$Configuration`

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PostBuildEvent>
    Call "$(ProjectDir)ConfigurationGenerator\ConfigurationGenerator.exe" "$(Configuration)" "$(OutDir)applicationConfiguration.config"
  </PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I'm not sure of what you're trying to explain here. Could you tell me where to have this configuration

Comment: If you open your .csproj file, this is the XML formatting the PostBuildEvents are stored in.

Comment: Okay, I'll try it

Comment: @MichaelNormand look at the output of the build window as Hans Passant pointed out.  It will show the full command being passed to your exe.

Comment: I got it! Thanks a lot guys!